# Creature which can see itself in third person

Tags: creature-design

On our earth there are various animals with strange visual capabilities, like seeing in 360 all at once or seeing heat, people with good hearing and various other animals can see with their ears.
I'm looking for the possibility of an animal to see themselves in third person. Imagine having a camera behind you floating around and following you all the time, but you see with the camera and not with your eyes.

Would be it possible for an animal to bend light in such a way to see themselves?

Comment: Do you want the view point to be beyond the whole body? I.e. no physical part of the creature is at that camera point

Comment: *"Creature which can see itself in third person":* Any sufficiently intelligent animal looking in a mirror, such as for example the surface of a body of still water? (Fun factoid: not only humans and chimpanzees are capable of [recognizing themselves in a mirror](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mirror_test), but also elephants, dolphins and magpies.)

Comment: Garden snail... maybe

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Let me propose something that might be of use or at least interesting.

**Two creatures in a symbiotic relationship.**

The first creature lacks any eyes. The second creature has at least one eye, and flies. The two creatures communicate via high frequency waves which are emitted from some specialized gland, and detect them via antenna which are tuned to the each other's resonance.

I'll leave it up to you to figure out what benefit the first creature offers the second.

Answer (score 3):

That wouldn't be possible, no. You could develop an alien creature with long eyestalks, which could then see most of its body from a 3rd person perspective.

A psychic creature, in a fictional setting, could probably see itself from third person, via a sort of constant astral projection. You could then make it totally blind, eyeless, and perhaps earless, so that no one understands how it can move about. It may develop an interesting psychological perspective due to this, having more awareness of its actions and its implications than most people. The creature could even look at itself, similarly to looking in a mirror.

I hope that was helpful.